# Releasing The Memory Used By Objects And Lists

Tags: c#, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection

I am trying to understand Garbage Collection process, and I think I got the idea. But when I works on some codes, It doesn't work as I expected.
In the code below, I just created  1.000.000 object and added them to a list. After a while, there is no object but memory stucks and not decreasing. How can I achieve to release the memory after all objects removed?

Thanks

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Test> tesst = new List<Test>();

        for (long i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            using (Test test = new Test())
            {

                test.LongObj = i;
                test.StrObj = i.ToString();
                test.DecObj = Convert.ToDecimal(i);
                tesst.Add(test);
            }
        }
        Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        proc.Refresh();
        label1.Text = Test.counter.ToString();
        label2.Text = (proc.PrivateMemorySize64 / 1048576).ToString();
        for (int i = 0; i < tesst.Count; i++)
        {
            tesst[i] = null;
        }
        tesst.Clear();
        tesst = null;

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        proc.Refresh();
        label1.Text = Test.counter.ToString();
        label2.Text = (proc.PrivateMemorySize64 / 1048576).ToString();
    }
```

And the sample class

```
    public class Test : IDisposable
{
    public static long counter = 0;

    public long LongObj { get; set; }
    public string StrObj { get; set; }
    public decimal DecObj { get; set; }

    public Test()
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref counter);
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly are you trying to release the memory manually?  There are valid reasons, but I want to make sure you are in a situation that requires it.

You can force a garbage collection by calling `GC.Collect()` and optionally with a parameter telling it which generation to collect.  You can read more about this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357(v=vs.110).aspx) and it includes a similar test to what you are attempting to do.

Comment: I am doing some operations in batch code, and I have memory problems. That is why I am trying to release memory manually.

Comment: When you try to allocate memory and there's too much "memory pressure" (i.e. memory needs to be freed up before allocating more), the GC will take care of that for you. It will clean it up right before allocating you more memory.  If you're getting an exception related to memory, that's a much better question to ask about.  In this case, you should just let it do it's thing.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I achieve to release the memory after all objects removed?

You don't, you let the GC do its job. Forcing the garbage collection (using `System.GC.Collect()`) is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: I have some memory problems in my batch operations. Is it normal that destructor is called but memory usage continues too long?

Comment: @TemporaryName If you actually have some memory issues, please post a reproducible example, you might have some memory leak somewhere in your code. 99.99% of time you shouldn't have to manually start a garbage collection. Also I'm not sure what your are calling a 'destructor' (it's not a C# very-friendly word). Assuming it's the finalizer, you probably don't want to create it either, unless you have unmanaged resources.

Comment: Yes.  As part of the garbage collection process, items are prepared for collection, marked as ready for collection, then eventually collected.  Calling the finalizer _usually_ happens in the preparing for collection phase.

Answer (score 0):

This really seems like a scenario where you need to rethink your process.  I don't think this is a job for manually interacting with GC.  Maybe if you post some of your code in a different question people can throw out some ideas on a different way to solve the problem?